# Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, lambda, functional-programming, invocation

I'm creating a lambda function that executes a second function with a concrete params. This code works in Firefox but not in Chrome, its inspector shows a weird error, `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`. What's wrong with my code?

```js
var make = function(callback,params){
    callback(params);
}

make(console.log,'it will be accepted!');
```

Comment: if i replace `console.log` with `console.log.bind(console)`, it works in Chrome 12.

Comment: @DanD—that indicates that *log* expects to be called as a method of *console*, i.e. that its *this* keyword must reference the *console* object.

Comment: your `make` function is equivalent to `callback.call(null,params)`

Comment: I would like to note that in old versions of IE console.log can be a callable host-object (without call, apply or bind methods) instead of being a function.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71283695/12910765

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The console's log function expects `this` to refer to the console (internally). Consider this code which replicates your problem:

```
var x = {};
x.func = function(){
    if(this !== x){
        throw new TypeError('Illegal invocation');
    }
    console.log('Hi!');
};
// Works!
x.func();

var y = x.func;

// Throws error
y();
```

Here is a (silly) example that will work, since it binds `this` to `console` in your make function:

```
var make = function(callback,params){
    callback.call(console, params);
}

make(console.log,'it will be accepted!');
```

This will also work

```
var make = function(callback,params){
    callback(params);
}

make(console.log.bind(console),'it will be accepted!');
```

Answer (score 4):

You can wrap the function which need 'this' to a new lambda function, and then use it for your callback function.

```
function make(callback, params) {
  callback(params);
}

make(function(str){ console.log(str); }, 'it will be accepted!');
```