# Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation error

Tags: ajax, backbone.js

I am trying to post an ajax request using jquery. and it causes a error:
  ###Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2###

```
CheckLogin: function (user, pword){
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('UserName', user);
    data.append('Password', pword);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'RegisterSuccess',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        processData: true,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false
    })
    .done(function () {
        console.log(user + " login back");
    })
    .fail(function () {
        self.showAlert('Error!', 'An error occurred while uploading ' + user, 'alert-error');
    });

}
```

I cannot get what's the problem. can anyone help??

Comment: May be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324594/jquery-illegal-invocation) can help.