# Unable to validate CSRF at controller in codeIgniter with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, csrf

I am new to CSRF and codeigniter. However, I have referred so many solution here and after applying I am able to go some extent but unable to validate the CSRF at controller end. I am getting the error

> The action you have requested is not allowed.

I am posting my entire code here. Though I am using this for registration but I am not using Form to submit the request but with the help of ajax.

**Config**

```
$config['csrf_protection']  = TRUE;
$config['csrf_token_name']  = 'csrfName';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'csrf_cookie_name';
$config['csrf_expire']      = 7200;
```

**View**

I am not going to post All the fields but few. Firstname, lastname, email, password.. etc are there

```
<?php 
$csrf = array(
    'csrfName' => $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(),
    'csrfHash' => $this->security->get_csrf_hash()
);
?>
<input type="hidden" class="csrfName" value="<?php echo $csrf['csrfName'];?>" />
<input type="hidden" class="csrfHash" value="<?php echo $csrf['csrfHash'];?>" />
<div class="row">
    <div id="join_btn" onclick="email_signup('joinBox')">SIGN UP</div>
</div>
```

**JS**

There are other fields as well but i am posting here important one

```
var csrfValue   = $(".csrfHash").val();
var csrfName    = $(".csrfName").val();
var callParameters = "call=email_signup&csrfHash="+csrfValue+"&csrfName="+csrfName;

$.ajax({
    url:ajaxcalls.php,
    data:callParameters,
    type:"POST",
    cache:false,
    dataType:"json",
    success: function(resp){

    }
});
```

**Controller**

```
function email_signup($params){
    $csrfName = $this->security->get_csrf_token_name();
    $csrfHash = $this->security->get_csrf_hash();

    $result['flag'] = "success";
    echo json_encode($result);

}
```

Comment: Typo. You're missing an `=` in the querystring you build. This is why it's better practice to provide a POJS object to `data` and let jQuery serialise it for you, where possible.

Comment: actually that's happened here while posting the question. My code has `=`. Howevent have edit my question. Result is same stil

Comment: In which case check how the `get_csrf_token_name()` and `get_csrf_hash()` methods expect to read the value. It's a little odd having them in the querystring. I would normally expect them to be sent as headers.

Comment: I am not using Form so this is the best I can send the value to controller. I don't know what to do next?

Comment: if you are using multi form this answere may help you
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69407364/6559546

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's because you're doing it all wrong.

### Mistake 1:

Your `type="hidden"` `input` elements have **no** `name=...` attributes.

### Mistake 2:

The `input` element that holds the `csrfName` i.e (`name="<?php echo $csrf['csrfName'];?>"`) expects a `csrfHash` as it's `value=...`.

In addition, both the `csrfName` and `csrfHash` need to be defined in one `input` HTML element. **Not** two.

[Cross-site request forgery (CSRF)](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/security.html?highlight=csrf#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf)

So:

```html
<!-- Instead of: -->

<input type="hidden" class="csrfName" value="<?php echo $csrf['csrfName'];?>" /> ❌
<input type="hidden" class="csrfHash" value="<?php echo $csrf['csrfHash'];?>" /> ❌


<!-- Use this: -->

<input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $csrf['csrfName'];?>" class="csrfName" value="<?php echo $csrf['csrfHash'];?>" />  ✅
```

### Suggestions

Since you're using jQuery already, to prepare your `POST` data, the [`.serializeArray()` method](https://api.jquery.com/serializearray/) would sound sufficient instead of manually building *'query strings'*. i.e:

```js
// ...

let $formData = $("form").serializeArray()

// ...
```

You can then [append any extra data you intend to pass along with the HTML form elements if you wish.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14102937/7376590).i.e:

```js
// ...
let $formData = $("form").serializeArray()

$formData.push({name: 'call', value: 'email_signup'})

$.ajax({
    // ...
    
    data: $formData,
    
    // ...
});
```

Alternatively, you can build the `POST` data using [`FormData()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData).

If you choose this option, [don't forget to add `processData: false` and `contentType: false` to your `$.ajax({...})` object argument](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22136177/7376590). i.e:

```js
let $formData = new FormData($("form").get(0))

$formData.append('call', 'email_signup')

$.ajax({
    // ...
    
    data: $formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Codeigniter vertion 3.0, add this in config:

```php
$config['csrf_regenerate'] = FALSE;
```