# jQuery, Convert $.ajax method to $.post

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, post, methods

i'm trying to make a simple form to upload files with jquery/ajax. this is a part of my code:

```
  var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

  $.ajax({
    url: 'uploader.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (data) {
      $('#ShowR').html(data);
    }
  });
```

i'm trying to change this code to $.post method like this:

```
var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

$.post('uploader.php', {action:"ShowGTR",MyFiles:formData},
function(data) {
 $('#ShowR').html(data);
});
```

i tried some ways but i couldn't fix the code and in Google Chrome console i got this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
```

so i need your help to fix this code and **convert $.ajax method to $.post method**. i really  appreciate if anyone can help me for this.

Comment: Are you trying to convert the $.ajax to $.post because you want to add a parameter to the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only reason you want to convert your $.ajax call to a $.post call is to add a parameter, then you don't need to convert it ro $.post. What you have to do is [append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) the parameter to the formdata object.

```
  var formData = new FormData(this);
  formData.append("action", "ShowGTR");

  $.ajax({
    url: 'uploader.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (data) {
      $('#ShowR').html(data);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score -3):

```
$.post( "ajax_file.php", {username:"someone"} ,function( data ) {
    $("#div-id").html(data);
});
```

This is general syntax of jquery post.

Comment: i know it! but my question is something else! how i can convert the ajax method (first code) to the post method (second code) :(

Comment: Try `var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]); console.log(formData);` What you see in console?

Comment: this is a new error: Uncaught ReferenceError: formData is not defined

Comment: So, it's error here. I don't know it but it's reference error. this what is this ? Value of this changes so it may causes error...

Comment: my dear friend, i think you didn't read my question! the first code is correct and working very well. but i need to use post method beside ajax! that's it! but thank you for answers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324594/jquery-illegal-invocation this may help you

Comment: try this, `var obj = {data: formData); $.post( "uploader.php", obj  ,function( data ) {
    $('#ShowR').html(data);
});` it's exact convert from ajax to post in jquery

Comment: I read your question and i am trying to answer you. Even i don't know exact answer. But I am trying to guess it. Anyway, I am going off now. hope you will solve it soon. bye