# Illegal Invocation using ajax and bootbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, bootbox

Good morning everyone.

So I've been working on this system using the bootbox plugin for jquery to make a nice series of windows and forms that do order processing and management and whatnot. In this particular case, I have a receiving function that upon the click of a link, fetches the order data, then builds a form and sends that form back. Then when I click submit it should still process but in this case I am getting an `illegal invocation`error. I have tried this function both with the ajax outside of the bootbox call, and inside the callback under `success`. I have had zero luck both ways, so I am hoping someone can help me solve this problem.

Here is my code below:

```
$('#new-inventory').on('click', '.receive', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $.ajax({
        url : 'assets/server/home/receive.php',
        type : 'POST',
        data : {id : id},
        dataType : 'JSON',
        success : function(data){
            bootbox.dialog({
                title : "Receive Tires",
                className : 'receive-tires-window',
                message : "<main class='row'>"+
                    "<section class='col-xs-12'>"+
                        data.message+
                    "</section>"+
                "</main>",
                buttons : {
                    success : {
                        label : 'Receive',
                        className : 'btn-success',
                        callback : function(){

                            e.preventDefault();
                            var formData = new FormData($('#rcvfrm')[0]);
                            $.ajax({ //error received right here
                                url : 'assets/server/home/process_receiving.php',
                                type : 'POST',
                                data : formData,
                                dataType : 'JSON',
                                success : function(data){
                                    if(!data.errors){
                                        bootbox.alert(data.message, function(){
                                            location.reload();
                                        });
                                    }else{
                                        bootbox.alert(data.message);
                                    }
                                }
                            });

                            return false;
                        }
                    },
                    danger : {
                        label : 'Cancel',
                        className : 'btn-danger',
                        callback : function(){

                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            $('.receive-tires-window').on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
                $('.receive-tires-window #recv_date').datepicker();
            });

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you post a fiddle?

Comment: It wouldn't do any good since all the data that generates the form comes from the server side

Comment: Can you then tell me which line you are receiving the error on?

Comment: sure thing, I have added a comment at the line where it happens. It's the second ajax call

Comment: is your server returning that error?

Comment: No it's the console log, the second request will not ever reach the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because jQuery ajax automatically tries to coerce the data to a string, which you have in an incoercible formadata object.

To fix this, you need to add these two options to the second request:

```
processData: false,
contentType: false
```

You can read more detailed explanation for the options [on the documentation.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324594/jquery-illegal-invocation) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax/5976031#5976031) questions.

Comment: sir you get the cookie for today! Thank you for that excellent explanation!