# Page reloads even after return false in ajax $.post request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to upload image after form submit using ajax call, having an issue that annoying me, the new `FormData($(this)[0])` gives me actual values, but whenever I try to send it through ajax its malfunctioning and reloads the page, so I cant see the console as well, please correct me where I am wrong.

**My javascript code**

```
$("#editImage").submit(function(){
var data = new FormData($(this)[0]);
console.log(data);
return false;
$.post("../galImages", data).done(function(response){
    console.log(response);
});
return false;});
```

**My HTML code**

```
<form name="edit-image" id="editImage" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"><input type="file" name="change-image" accept="image/*" class="form-control mb-20" value="Upload Image">
                    <input type="hidden" name="edit-img-id" id="editImageId"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save Changes" id="submitEditImgForm"></form>
```

however file datas are posted in the PHP page, and one more thing how can I send hidden field value along with formdata object. I am a noobie in ajax `$.post` method. Please help me if anyone have any idea.

Comment: in jQuery `.submit` you should prevent default behavior for processing the form/data maybe ? what about the form (target url in it) ?

Comment: @OldPadawan I have updated the html part

Comment: then, I guess [preventDefault](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) would do it

Comment: Throws `Illegal invocation` now

Comment: [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324594/jquery-illegal-invocation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you upload an image (my mistake, forgot that first!) :
Important parts are the ones `needed for upload` otherwise it will fail

```
$(function () {
$('#my_form').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $form = $(this);
    var formdata = (window.FormData) ? new FormData($form[0]) : null;
    var data = (formdata !== null) ? formdata : $form.serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: $form.attr('action'),
        type: $form.attr('method'),
        contentType: false, // needed for upload
        processData: false, // needed for upload
        dataType: 'json', // return
        data: data,
        success: function (response) {
            // response
        }
     });
   });
});
```

This code is not mine, found it, adapted it long time ago, can't credit its original owner as I don't remember who she/he is :/

Comment: UR welcome. Good code for the future, and sorry for the mate who 'gave' us this portion of code and won't get credit for it...

Answer (score 0):

Use `preventDefault()` this will prevent the default behaviour of the form and the page from reloading.

```
$("#editImage").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = new FormData($(this)[0]);
    console.log(data);
    return false;
    $.post("../galImages", data).done(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thank you @julekgwa, seems like its working, page stops reloading but there is an error in console.log, `Illegal invocation`, that prevents the page to send data to the destination php file