# Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation error on sending from data from jquery to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to send a form data from html page to PHP using JQuery and I am getting this **error**,

I am trying to send a few files as from data and some other string also,

```
jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
    at e (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
    at Ab (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
    at Ab (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
    at Function.r.param (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
    at Function.ajax (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (script.js:68)
    at HTMLFormElement.dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)
    at HTMLFormElement.q.handle (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)
```

**​script.js**

```
$('form').submit(function (e) {
            flag = true;
            e.preventDefault();
            var forms = new FormData(this);
            $(this).find('input').each(function (i, ele) {
                console.log('.' + $(ele).val().split('.')[$(ele).val().split('.').length - 1]);
                console.log(fileType);
                if ($(ele).val() != 'Upload' && fileType.indexOf('.' + $(ele).val().split('.')[$(ele).val().split('.').length - 1]) == -1) {
                    $("#error").html('Invalid File Format')
                    flag = false;
                } else if ($(ele).val() == 'Upload') {


                }


            });
            if (flag) {
                console.log('sends');
    /*line 68*/     $.ajax({
                    url: "uploaderhandler.php",
                    type: "post",
                    data: {
                        form: forms,
                        ids: ids,
                        content: current
                    },
                    success: function (response) {


                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
                    }


                });
            }
         else {
            $("#error").html('Only ' + fileType.toString() + ' Formats can be uploaded')
        }


    });


});
```

how to rectify this error??

Comment: Possible duplicate [jQuery - Illegal invocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324594/jquery-illegal-invocation)