# Illegal Invocation error when console.log passed in a function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am bit confused over this.
Please find the code as below.

```
var o={
 printToConsole: function(f){
   f(1);
}
};

o.printToConsole(console.log);
```

`//TypeError: Illegal invocation`// I get a TypeError

From the definition of console.log we get this

```
`function log() { [native code] }`
```

In chrome, which clearly displays that it doesn't take any argument, though when we try to print things on console we do write like this i.e. pass the argument to console.log.

```
console.log('Take me on Console');
```

Why I am getting this TypeError and how this console.log behaves in chrome?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change

```
o.printToConsole(console.log);
```

to

```
o.printToConsole(console.log.bind(console));
```

or

```
o.printToConsole(function(){ console.log.apply(console.log, arguments) });
```

The `console.log` function only works when the receiver (`this`) is the console (in fact, it's browser dependent).

Comment: Firefox displays message in console without binding it with the console.

Comment: Found a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8904782/uncaught-typeerror-illegal-invocation-in-javascript

Comment: the ```bind()``` method worked well for me in Chrome