# JavaScript anonymous function in the for loop error

Tags: javascript, function, object, prototype

Hello I was reading "JavaScript: the definitive guide" 6th edition and tried one of the examples at  9.1 Classes and Prototypes.

```
function range (from, to) {
    var r = Object.create(range.methods);

    r.from = from;
    r.to = to;
    return r;
}

range.methods = {
    includes: function(x) { 
        return this.from <= x && x <= this.to; 
    },
    foreach: function(f) {
        for(var x = Math.ceil(this.from); x <= this.to; x++) 
            f(x);
    },
    toString: function() { 
        return "(" + this.from + "..." + this.to + ")"; 
    }
};
```

Loading this into console throws an error

> Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation class.js:31. 
>   range.methods.foreach class.js:31
>   (anonymous function)

I guess intention of foreach method is to pass a function name as an argument

```
var r = range(1, 3);
r.foreach(console.log);
```

Any ideas how to fix this error?

Comment: I think that is something with `console.log`, [look](http://jsfiddle.net/NN38C/)

Comment: [Illegal Invocation error when console.log passed in a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18426408/illegal-invocation-error-when-console-log-passed-in-a-function)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It happens because you detached `log` method from `console` object, while `console.log` expects context (`this`) to be `console`, not `Window` as it becomes when you lose context. If you want to use `console.log` as a function you should explicitly tell it what context to use.

```
r.foreach(console.log.bind(console));
```

[Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) is your friend in this case.

For future readers: ES6 style would also allow you to use arrow functions for this which would be even more concise:

```
r.foreach(x => console.log(x))
```

Comment: @techfoobar Soon there will be another classical way to do it `r.foreach(x => console.log(x))` :)

Comment: Hmm.. I need to stay upto date on the specs. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 4):

Log cannot be called outside of the console object, you're passing in the function, but not the context.

```
r.foreach(function(a){
    console.log(a);
});
```

This works without any issues.

Comment: Nice, it works, but why ? In fact it was called with the object console, right ?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown When you pass a function you pass the function, but not the parent information, calling the function inside your loop then runs into an issue of the `this` object being the window instead of the console, and the function generates an error.