# Can I use console.log inside forEach in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Why does the second line throw an error?

```
[0,1,2].forEach(function(x) { console.log(x) }); // prints 0, 1, 2
[0,1,2].forEach(console.log); // throws "TypeError: Illegal invocation"
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Bound_functions_used_as_constructors

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8904782/uncaught-typeerror-illegal-invocation-in-javascript