# how to pass an array elements to log set of parameters in one line

Tags: javascript, arguments, prototype

Once upon a time I ad an assignment task on one of interviews that hasn't been giving me to sleep since:

Need to log a `arguments`-object in `console` in one line with a date in the end. As objects(to be able to inspect those), not string( `Array prototype.join()` - is not a solution in this case)

a fail attempt(out of function scope):

```
var fn = function () {
  var arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  arr.push(new Date().toJSON());
  Function.prototype.call.apply( console.log, arr );  
}

fn( 1, 'a', [2, 3], {a:1} );
```

logs:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
```

Any ideas?

Comment: why are you not saying `console.log(arr);` instead of `Function.prototype.call.apply( console.log, arr );  `.

Comment: you are going to see an array with objects.

Comment: if that would be sooo easy...=)

Comment: can you try this for logging `  Function.prototype.call.apply( console.log.bind(console), arr );  ` & let me know...

Comment: oh yeah baby! it works!

Comment: `console.log.apply(console, [].slice.call(arguments).concat("the date"));`

Comment: added as answer.... @NikTerentyev

Answer (score 0):

Use this for logging

```
Function.prototype.call.apply( console.log.bind(console), arr );
```

instead of

```
Function.prototype.call.apply( console.log, arr );
```

It will do the work.

Comment: I'm not sure, but what I know... **The console's log function expects this to refer to the console (internally). when passed as callback.** [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8904782/uncaught-typeerror-illegal-invocation-in-javascript)

Comment: This is incorrect. You're losing the first argument because it tries to be bound as the `this` value of the `log` method via `.call()`, but you've already bound `this`, so it gets ignored.