# Can not call legacy function in javascript as delegate

Tags: javascript

Sorry about this really stupid question, but why this code is not working?

```
var ar = [1,2,3];
ar.forEach(console.log);
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Define "not working". `console.log` requires context, though. Use `console.log.bind(console)` or (ES6) `a => console.log(a)`

Comment: what do you mean by "doesn't work"?  I can think of a couple issues: 1) log expects a parameter that isn't there and 2) log only gets called in the debugger in some browsers

Comment: Thanks @JanDvorak , that's what I needed: "requires context, though"

Answer (score -1):

Because You need to pass to the .forEach an anonymous function:

```
ar.forEach(function(el, index, array){
  console.log(index);
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: Yes, I know this. But console.log is also a function which can accept this args. Why I can not pass it instead?

Comment: @Mutex http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8904782/uncaught-typeerror-illegal-invocation-in-javascript - first answer