# firebase-admin illegal invocation error onSnapshot event

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, electron, firebase-admin

Hi I am Getting an Illegal invocation error onSnapshot event
Any help?

```
const { Console } = require('console');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const path = require('path');
const serviceAccount = require('./serviceAccountKey.json');
const app = admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://xxxxxx.firebaseio.com"
});
const db = admin.firestore();
db.settings({
  timestampsInSnapshots: true
});

db.collection("connected_device").doc("CDEA7846-68CF-4C7E-8FD9-846AFD258181").onSnapshot((doc) => {
  console.log("Current data: ", doc.data());
}, err => {
  console.log('Encountered error' + err);
  //Encountered errorTypeError Illegal invocation
});
```

error block I am getting the error: Encountered errorTypeError: Illegal invocation.
Write operation is working perfectly!
Here is my database[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to show the exact/complete error message and stack trace.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen update the code could you please have a look I am using this in my electron desktop application

Comment: Could you share the database structure that you are using here? Also, you may have a look at this [Stackoverflow case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8904782/uncaught-typeerror-illegal-invocation-in-javascript/8904853#8904853) which is also having similar issue. Let me know if that helps!

Comment: @MousumiRoy Updated the DB structure

Comment: It seems you have already created [a github issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/1589). I would suggest you follow up there to get a better resolution.